# wso2 esb proxy rest service no response

Tags: wso2-esb

[image: screenshot soap request]

proxy config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="person"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address format="pox" uri="http://localhost:8181/person/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="text/xml"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

[image: screenshot postman]

Request message can not get response message template:

[image: screenshot endpoint template name]

The template:

[image: screenshot xml template]

This is the console log output:

[image: screenshot console log]

Comment: do you see the logs which you have added?

Comment: Based on the log my guess is that your loacalhost:8281/person/ endpoint returns an empty response which then gets propagated back to soapui. If you want to test, you can try for instance 'mocky.io' to create a dummy response and use that as endpoint instead: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5da99e043100006a004e0a36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with this,

```
<endpoint name="IdentityDSSserviceEP" template="esbendpoint" uri="http://localhost:8181/person/"/>
```

Template (Sample template)

```
<template xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="esbendpoint">
   <endpoint name="$name">
      <address uri="$uri">
         <suspendOnFailure>
            <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
            <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
         </suspendOnFailure>
         <markForSuspension>
            <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
         </markForSuspension>
         <timeout>
            <duration>60000</duration>
            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
         </timeout>
      </address>
   </endpoint>
</template>
```

Comment: Still no response

Comment: did yoo create template? You can tail log and check

Comment: I put up the screenshot of the application,Take a look for me

Comment: That seems okay, Did you change in the proxy config? Add endpoint like this.
<endpoint name="IdentityDSSserviceEP" template="esbendpoint" uri="http://localhost:8181/person/"/>

Comment: It has been settled. Thank you very much

Comment: If its help you , Please accept the answer ad upvote it :)